# リスト処理をする自前クラスで、書き込みアクセス違反が出る。

Tags: c++, c++11

C言語を終えてC++の初学者なんですが、C言語のリスト処理をクラスを使って書いてみようと思い自分なりに書いているのですが。下のあたりのコメントで`[//書き込みアクセス違反]`となっている部分の修正方法を教えてもらいたいです。できれば解説もお願いします。

```
/*
int main(){
    list test;
    test = 5;

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
*/

/*
class list {
    private:
        typedef struct struct_list {
            int height, width;
            string name;

            struct struct_list *prev, *next;

        }st_list;

        st_list *p, *t,*date; int n;
        st_list *start;//先頭のポインタを保存
        int number;//入力した数

    public:
        list():n(0),number(0){};//デフォルトコンストラクタ

        list(int x);//コンストラクタ
};
*/

list::list(int x) {
    number = x;//リスト作成数を決める
    int a = 0;

    do {
    /*
    do {
        cout << "リストを作りますか? [YES --- 0 / NO --- 9]: ";
        cin >> n;

        if (n != 0 && n != 9)
        {
            cout << "0か9を入力してください\n";
        }
    } while (n != 9);
    */

        date = new st_list;

        cout << "身長を入力してください:"; cin >> date->height;
        cout << "名前を入力してください:"; cin >> date->name;
        cout << "体重を入力してください:"; cin >> date->width;

        date->next = NULL;

        if (start == NULL)
        {
            date->prev = NULL;
            start = date;
            p = date;
        }
        else {/*先頭以降*/
            p->next = date;//書き込みアクセス違反
            date->prev = p;
            p = date;
        }

        ++a;

    } while (a != number);

}
```

Comment: タイトルにはご質問の内容だけ書いて下さい。C++であることはタグに、初心者であることは本文に書いて頂ければ充分です。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コード部分が大量にコメントアウトしてあるため、コードが読みにくくなっています。本文を修正して頂けませんか？

Comment: また、エラーが出ている場合、そのエラーを省略せずにすべてコピー＆ペーストして頂いた方が的確なアドバイスができます。

Comment: 前の質問のコメントにもありましたが、質問しっぱなしではなく、回答によって質問が解決したのであれば、[回答を承認し](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)て、問題が解決したことを表明し、そうで無いのであれば、回答のどの部分が不明なため未解決であるかを、問題を編集して再質問する様にして下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メンバー変数`start`が、初期化されていないようです。C++の仕様では、初期化されていないポインタの値は不定で、何が入っていても構いません。`nullptr`以外の値が入っていると、一番最初の要素を追加するときでも、`if (start == NULL)`が`false`になってしまい、`else`の部分が実行されてしまいます。一番最初だと、`p`もまだ初期化されておらず、書き込みアクセス違反などの、いろいろな問題が起きてしまいます。

```
list::list(int x) : start(nullptr) {
```

などのように、`start`を`nullptr`に初期化しましょう (デフォルトコンストラクタでも同様に)。

Comment: Hideki さん回答ありがとうございます。クラスを理解するためにこのプログラムを組んだのですが この先を使うのでしょうか？、それとクラスがあるから構造体は使わないとか聞きますけど使いますか？

Comment: @beginner 前半の質問は、申し訳ないですが、何をお聞きになっているのか、わかりません。後半の質問は、真面目に答えると、クラスの設計の仕方について語ることになって、スタック・オーバーフローになじまないと思いますが、個人的にどうかということなら、構造体を使うこともあります(本質的には`class`も`struct`も同じですが、C言語のような使い方という意味で)。